# How can I get each line of prosrc from pg_proc?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I'm new on PostgreSQL and have a question.
I'd like to make whole code on `prosrc` of `pg_proc` like in Oracle's `user_source`.

```
select prosrc
from pg_proc 
where proname= 'function_name'
```

`prosrc` is of type `text`, so I want get every single line with a `for` loop.
So, the first line can be like this

```
DECLARE v_sp_nm         varchar;
```

and the second one will be

```
v_exec_cd       VARCHAR(1);
```

Is it possible to use a `for` loop statement here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit unclear, but you can use `regexp_split_to_table(prosrc, E'\n')` to split a string into lines of text.

It should be easy to loop through the resulting lines.

Disclaimer: I don't know if Greenplum, being a very old fork of PostgreSQL, has this function.

Comment: That's it! It's really what I wanted. Thank you!